# Inserting the content control in word using office js word api

Tags: office-js, contentcontrol

I want to add the content control in word using office js word api. I am using insertContentControl method but this method is not adding at the end of the document or at the particular insert location.
Below is my code:-

```
Word.run(function (context) {


            var body = context.document.body;
            var contents = body.contentControls;
            // Queue a commmand to wrap the body in a content control.
            var a = body.insertContentControl();
            a.appearance = "name";
            a.tag = "name1";
            a.title = "name";


            return context.sync().then(function () {
               // context.load(body);
                console.log('Wrapped the body in a content control.');
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {

            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
```

Also I want to add the properties to it like appearance,tag,title to the new content control created

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the documentation of insertContentControl() it will wrap the entire body as content control, it wont add a new content control at last. this is from the documentation

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body

If you want to add a new content control in your add-in you ooxml apis with that it is possible to insert a new content control.